# Django template time filter not rendering

Tags: python, django

I have a little issue with Django's template not really rendering the time format as I'd like it to, following the documentations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time) proved to be a bit troublesome as it didn't work.

Original Code:

```
<p>Obtained this item on {{date_variable|date:"M j, Y"}} at {{time_variable|time}}</p>
```

Tried these two time filter formats as shown below which are given by the Django's documentation.

```
{{time_variable|time}}
{{time_variable|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}
```

They represent the same thing as stated by the documentations. I even went as far as to try different formats i.e. `{{time_variable|time:"h:i A"}}`, `{{time_variable|time:"P"}}` etc. but none of it rendered in the web application.

One solution I miraculously found was by removing the time filter `{{time_variable}}` and it showed the time entered from the form except the AM/PM. However, I **need to display the AM/PM**, looking to try for other solutions.

Django version used is 2.2.2.

**Note**: I have tried other solutions that are on stackoverflow but it seemed none of them worked, I don't really know why either as the information is entered through Django's form template, not processed or changed.

Comment: Hi, here is working just fine on django 2.2.2. Could you please show the type of those field on the view/model?

Comment: @EliakinCosta 
oh really?hmm, one other thing that might be the cause of it should be that it's being returned as a string instead of a datetime object, could this be the reason?

Comment: Yeah, probably that's the reason. You should be returning those fields as raw date and time fields.@m00ncake.

Comment: @EliakinCosta ok, ill give it a shot. One thing ill like to ask though is...should it be necessary to try use the django's clean function for the form template on the time data? or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the Django template (well at least for my project), the user inserts the time e.g.`1:23 AM` which is accepted and stored as a string due to `AM` so therefore it needs to be processed, that is, use the `strptime()` in python to convert the string back into a datetime object which can be then displayed using the following `{{time_variable|time:'%h:%i A'}}` or `{{time_variable|time}}` in the Django template.